# SQL multiple field un-pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016, unpivot

I have data as below

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(OrderId int, Country varchar(100),Area varchar(100),Hotel varchar(100),CountryDetail varchar(100),AreaDetail varchar(100),HotelDetail varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES(1,'Bhutan','Thimphu','Taj Tashi','Bhutan country info','Thimphu area info','Taj Tashi hotel info'),
      (2,'Bhutan','Punakha','COMO Uma Punakha','Bhutan country info','Punakha area info','COMO Uma Punakha hotel info'),
      (3,'Bhutan','Punakha','COMO Uma Paro','Bhutan country info','Punakha area info','COMO Uma Paro hotel info')
```

Expected output I am after

```
Item                    ItemDetail                      OrderId
Bhutan                  Bhutan country info                 1 
Thimphu                 Thimphu area info                   1
Taj Tashi               Taj Tashi hotel info                1
Punakha                 Punakha area info                   2
COMO Uma Punakha        COMO Uma Punakha hotel info         2
COMO Uma Paro           COMO Uma Paro hotel info            3
```

Output is based on not duplicating country, area or hotel and display only once as per orderid

Tried so far

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT OrderId,Country,Area,Hotel,CountryDetail,AreaDetail,HotelDetail,            
              CountryDupe = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY OrderId),
              AreaDupe = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY OrderId),
               HotelDupe = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Hotel ORDER BY OrderId)
from #TEMP)

SELECT ITEM, OrderId
FROM (SELECT OrderId,CountryDetail,
                CASE WHEN CountryDupe=1 THEN Country ELSE '' END AS Country,
                CASE WHEN AreaDupe = 1 THEN Area ELSE '' END AS Area,
                CASE WHEN HotelDupe = 1 THEN Hotel ELSE '' END AS Hotel
     FROM CTE) P
UNPIVOT(
ITEM
FOR ITEMS IN (Country,Area,Hotel)
) UNPVT
WHERE LEN(ITEM)>1
ORDER BY OrderId
```

Not sure how to pull related item detail here.

SQL FIDDLE [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97520/1)

Comment: Why are there only 2 rows for Order 2 and 1 row for Order 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some odd logic, however, you can use the table constructor `VALUES` to unpivot the data, and then `ROW_NUMBER` to only return the "first" order:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT V.Item,
           V.ItemDetail,
           T.OrderId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.Item, V.ItemDetail ORDER BY T.OrderId ASC) AS RN
    FROM #TEMP T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(T.Country, T.CountryDetail),
                            (T.Area, T.AreaDetail),
                            (T.Hotel, T.HotelDetail))V(Item, ItemDetail))
SELECT RNs.Item,
       RNs.ItemDetail,
       RNs.OrderId
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY RNs.OrderId ASC;
```

Comment: . . .  You need `ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to unpivot the data.  I recommend `cross apply`:

```
select t.orderid, v.item, v.itemdetail
from temp t cross apply
     (values (country, countrydetail),
             (hotel, hoteldetail)
     ) v(item, itemdetail);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac5745e610909c54f8be52996aa7bead) is a db<>fiddle.